# Identifying the relationship between the output of two functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have two real numbers x and y.

$$x = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \\
y = \sqrt{(a+k)^2 + (b+k)^2}$$

How can I identify a function $f$ such that

$$y = f(x)$$

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2(a+b)k+2 k^2}\,$. Since this is most likely not the answer you were looking for, please revise your question to include the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't, since $y$ depends on $k$ but $x$ doesn't depend on $k$. If you could write $y=f(x)$, the value of $y$ would be independent of $k$, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can't. The problem is that there are several different values of $a$ and $b$ which would correspond to the same $x$, but they would yield different values of $y$.

For example, say $k=1$, and

$$x=\sqrt {1^2 + 1^2}=\sqrt 2$$

so we should have

$$f(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt{(1+k)^2+(1+k)^2}=\sqrt 8$$

but on the other hand, $x=\sqrt 2$ can also be written as

$$x=\sqrt{\sqrt 2^2 + 0^2}$$

in which case

$$f(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt{(\sqrt 2 + k)^2+(0 + k)^2}=\sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt 2}$$